# Assertion failure in UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Getting this error when I load my tableview and I'm not sure why:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:7344

I've added a `UITableViewController` in my storyboard and I'm using the prototype cells to design the cell. I linked the cell to my custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and I set its reuse identifier to "Cell". I am getting the assertion failure when I call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. From what I've read, this happens when I don't set the reuse identifier in the prototype cell, however I've checked countless times and it's the same identifier I'm using when I dequeue it.

Here are my datasource methods In the `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LanguageSelectionTableViewCell *cell = (LanguageSelectionTableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try adding cell identifier in storyboard

Comment: @Sam I've added an identifier named "Cell" to the prototype cell in the storyboard

Comment: just try changing identifier name other than Cell if it works

Comment: can you share sample app on Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the tableviewcell with the given reusablecellidentifier "Cell".

Example code is given below.

```
[yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YouTableViewCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```